# Discord with requests (python) send commands (message with /)

Tags: python, discord

I want to send a command like this '/checklist' but it just doesn't work.
[for example in captcha.bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGGEX.jpg)

```
import requests

token = 'my_token'
channel_id = my_channel_is
message = '/checklist'
 
def sendMessage(token, channel_id, message):
    url = 'https://discord.com/api/v8/channels/{}/messages'.format(channel_id)
    data = {
        "content": message
    }
    header = {"authorization": token}
 
    r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=header)

sendMessage(token, channel_id, message)
```

Comment: Please write your error message

Comment: It' doesn't make any error, it send just like a normal message. I want to send it like command.

Comment: What do you mean with command?

Comment: command example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGGEX.jpg